# How to view Output and Debug Console in Visual Studio Code at the same time?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Maybe a stupid question, but I'm unable to find the setting where it would enable it. Right now, if I enable one, the other is hidden. It's very annoying.

Comment: Yes, I would have preferred the single lower panel to have tabs with wrap too or at least split-able with wrap.

Comment: There's no way atm. But, you can always write a plugin that does that.

Answer (score 1):

With the **January/17** update you now see `Output`, `Problems`, `Debug Console` and `Terminal`, at the same time. Just click in the titles to switch between them.

[image: Panels title bar update]

Comment: Can I somehow have them in 2 tabs?

Answer (score 1):

With v1.44 you can now drag any of the panel items into the explorer area to see both at the same time: (demo from Insiders' Build)

[image: moving views]